# Configuring SELINUX to allow logging to a file that's outside /var/log

Tags: linux, syslog, selinux

I have a daemon that uses syslog(3) to log to a file that is not a descendant of /var/log. Currently, this requires that SELINUX be disabled. How can I configure an enabled SELINUX to allow this logging?

I am an SELINUX novice. Any guidance or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cory, good idea. Done. Curious to see which exchange answers first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the context of your logging directory. For example you want to log into /mnt/extranal/log instead of /var/log.

So you have to set SELinux type for /mnt/external/log to var_log_t as well as the /var/log already has.

Check

```
ls -Z /var
```

with result

```
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0   log
```

prepare your log directory

```
mkdir /mnt/external/log
```

prepare rules for labeling FS by SELinux

```
semanage fcontext -a -t var_log_t /mnt/external/log
```

invoke relabeling of your directory

```
restorecon -v /mnt/external/log
```

if you've done, check

```
ls -Z /mnt/external
```

with result

```
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0   log
```

That's all if you don't use MLS/MCS policy.

See more details on

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html